# CTE - LEFT OUTER JOIN Performance Problem

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

Using SQL Server 2017.

SQL FIDDLE: [LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1dcd3/1)

```
CREATE TABLE [TABLE_1] 
(
    PLAN_NR decimal(28,6) NULL,
    START_DATE datetime  NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE [TABLE_2] 
(
    PLAN_NR decimal(28,6) NULL,
    PERIOD_NR decimal(28,6) NULL,
);

INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (PLAN_NR, START_DATE)
VALUES (1, '2020-05-01'), (2, '2020-08-05');

INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (PLAN_NR, PERIOD_NR)
VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 17),  
       (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 5), (2, 2), (2, 17), (2, 28);

CREATE VIEW ALL_PERIODS
AS
    WITH rec_cte AS 
    (
        SELECT 
            PLAN_NR, START_DATE,
            1 period_nr, DATEADD(day, 7, START_DATE) next_date
        FROM 
            TABLE_1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            PLAN_NR, next_date,
            period_nr + 1, DATEADD(day, 7, next_date)
        FROM 
            rec_cte       
        WHERE 
            period_nr < 100       
  ),
  cte1 AS 
  (
      SELECT 
          PLAN_NR, period_nr, START_DATE
      FROM 
          rec_cte
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 
          PLAN_NR, period_nr, DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(next_date, -1)) 
      FROM 
          rec_cte
      WHERE 
          MONTH(START_DATE) <> MONTH(next_date)
  ),
  cte2 AS (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PLAN_NR ORDER BY START_DATE) rn
FROM cte1
)
SELECT PLAN_NR, rn PERIOD_NR, START_DATE 
FROM cte2
WHERE rn <= 100
```

Table_1 lists plans (PLAN_NR) and their start date (START_DATE).
Table_2 lists plan numbers (PLAN_NR) and periods (1 - X). Per plan number periods can appear several times but can also be missing.
A period lasts seven days, unless the period includes a change of month. Then the period is divided into a part before the end of the month and a part after the end of the month.

The view ALL_PERIODS lists 100 periods per plan according to this system.

My problem is the performance of the following select which I would like to use in a view:

```
SELECT 
t2.PLAN_NR
, t2.PERIOD_NR
, a_p.START_DATE 
from TABLE_2 as t2 
left outer join ALL_PERIODS a_p on t2.PERIOD_NR = a_p.PERIOD_NR and t2.PLAN_NR = a_p.PLAN_NR
```

From about 4000 entries in TABLE_2 the select becomes incredibly slow.

The join itself does not yet slow down the query. Only with the additional select a_p.START_DATE everything becomes incredibly slow.

I read the view into a temporary table and did the join over that and got no performance issues. (2 seconds for the 4000 entries).

So I assume that the CTE used in the view is the reason for the slow performance.
Unfortunately I can't use temporary tables in views and I would hate to write the data to a normal table.

Is there a way in SQL Server to improve the CTE lag?

Comment: What indexes do you have defined on your tables? And what does the query plan look like?

Comment: Why use `decimal(28,6)` when you're only inserting integers?

Comment: decimal(28,6) was just used out of habit. Multiple Indexes defined n the tables... but I guess they don't fit the minimal example from the sql fiddle. Would i make sense to extend the fiddel

Comment: Replace the rCTE with a tally table for example [this one](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/12/t-sql-queries/number-series-challenge) by @ItzikBenGan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a recusive CTE, generate ALL_PERIODS with a CROSS join between the Plan table and a "number table" either persisted, or as a non-recursive CTE.

EG

```
WITH N As
(
   select top 100 row_number() over (order by (select null)) i
   from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10) ) v1(i),
        (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10) ) v2(i)
),
plan_period AS 
(
    SELECT 
        PLAN_NR, START_DATE,
        N.i period_nr, DATEADD(day, 7*N.i, START_DATE) next_date
    FROM TABLE_1 CROSS JOIN N
),
```

Comment: Thank you but as far as i can see that way I don't get extra period split on each months end like in the original cte.

Comment: Then I would definitely pre-calculate and store the periods for each plan.

Answer (score 0):

if you are able to modify the view I would recommend to do this :

1. add a table containing numbers starting from 0 to whatever you think you will need in database, you can use below command :

```
create table numbers ( id int)
go
;with cte (
  select 0 num
  union all
  select num + 1
  where num < 2000 -- change this 
)

insert into number
from num from cte
```

2. change the first cte in the view to this :

```
    WITH rec_cte AS 
    (
          
  SELECT
        PLAN_NR
        , DATEADD(DAY, 7* id, START_DATE) START_DATE
        , id  +1                        period_nr
        , DATEADD(DAY, 7*( id+1), START_DATE) next_date

    FROM
        TABLE_1 t
        CROSS apply intenum  i 
         WHERE i.id <100       
  ),...
```

3. Also consider using temp table instead of cte it might be helpful

Comment: temp table worked wonders but as a I mentioned I would like the  solution working within a view where I can't use temp tables

Comment: then keep the ctes and replace recursive cte with the given solution in step 1 and 2